# Postgres CHECK constraint executing before ON CONFLICT

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, upsert

I have this historical stock movements table, that saves the stock losses per day:

```sql
CREATE TABLE stock (
    item_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    quantity INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (quantity >= 0),
    
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id, date)
);
```

And this INSERT/ON CONFLICT (To update instead, atomically):

```sql
INSERT INTO stock.loss (item_id, date, quantity)
VALUES(2, '2021-10-03', -1)
ON CONFLICT (item_id, date)
DO
UPDATE SET quantity = stock.quantity + excluded.quantity;
```

With this, I insert a movement for a day, or update it if it already exists.

The thing is, if "quantity" is negative (see query above), the CHECK constraint throws:

```
SQL Error [23514]: ERROR: new row for relation "stock" violates check constraint "stock_quantity_check"
  Detail: Failing row contains (2, 2021-10-03, -1).
```

If I change the INSERT to an UPDATE, it works as expected. As I see, it's running the check on the temporary row instead of the final row, after the ON CONFLICT.

Is there any way to avoid this, and keep the CHECK? I would prefer to avoid a SELECT+INSERT/UPDATE, and make a direct "upsert".

Comment: Constraints are generally processed first.  There are some constraints that can be deferred, `CHECK` is not one of them. Change the `CHECK` to a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Comment: I see. As I'm using that INSERT inside a procedure, I think I'll add a condition to do an UPDATE if the value is negative then, to keep the CHECK. Thanks!